# Character equality in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to do an equality test like this

`equal? somevar #\space`

but it seems this never evaluates to true even when `somevar=#\space`.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: `(equal somevar #\space)` should work perfectly. SO isn't a guessing game but a common error is to compare a single letter string (like `" "`) with a character (like `#\space`) and it won't work since `equal?` will evalute to `#f` if the elements being compared are of different type. Please edit your post with more code if you want further help.

Answer (score 3):

The most direct equality comparison procedure to use between characters would be [`char=?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._char~3d~3f%29%29):

```
(define somevar #\space)
(char=? somevar #\space)
=> #t
```

Of course, you can always use `equal?`, but if `equal?` isn't working, then it's possible that the problem is elsewhere. Check the variables being used in the comparison, there's a good chance that they have a different value or a different type, which would explain the error. In particular make sure that `somevar` is truly a *character* and not a *string*; for example this comparison is `false`:

```
(equal? " " #\space)
=> #f
```

Comment: Yes I suspect you are right, see my comment above to @soegaard.

Comment: @user35202 in fact, you're reading a single-char _string_. Make your comparison like this: `(equal? somevar " ")` … and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The funtion `equal?` should work.

```
> (define a #\space)
> (define b #\space)
> (equal? a b)
#t
```

The problem must be something else.

How do you give `somevar` a value?

Comment: somevar is the value of the call to this function (define (peek port) (read-string 1 (peeking-input-port port))). Since this is a string I have also tried equality testing against "\\space".

Comment: You can use `read-char` to read a single character - or in your case perhaps use `peek-char`.

Comment: Also a string with a single space is simply " "